# A woman has two babies. One of them is a girl, what is the probability that the other is a boy?

Tags: probability

This question has been asked many times. However, I still have trouble to understand what really is asking.

> A woman has two babies. One of them is a girl, what is the probability
>   that the other is a boy?

Pr{other is boy | 1 girl}  $\neq$ Pr{other is boy | **at least 1 girl**)

I am having difficulty seeing whether the question is asking at least 1 girl, or simply 1 girl?

Thanks

Comment: It is heavily implied that the problem statement is intending to give us the condition that the woman has *at least one* girl (*as opposed to exactly one girl*) since it is asking us for the probability of the other being a boy versus a girl (*otherwise it seems kind of silly to be told "a woman has a boy and a girl, what is the probability that the boy is a boy?"*)

Comment: The definite article "the" implies that the woman has **one and only one** girl baby. If she had two girl babies, which is "the other"? It would make no sense.

Comment: The phrasing is slightly misleading in that it implies that one specified kid (like "the oldest one" or "this one here") is a daughter. They don't really say it, but it's how one would read that sentence if it wasn't a math problem.

Comment: If one baby one of two babies is a girl then the other baby is clearly a boy. Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of boys. And similar $Y$ the number of girls.

Then $P(X=x)=P(X=x,Y=2-x)=\binom{2}{x}\cdot p^x\cdot (1-p)^{2-x}$

You see that if the value of $X$ is given the value of $Y$ is indirectly given as well. Et vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means at least one girl, since otherwise the exercise would be trivial.
$$ \begin{array}{l|cc} & \text{1st child} & \text{2nd child} \\ \hline \text{1st possibility} & \text{girl} & \text{girl} \\ \text{2nd} & \text{girl} & \text{boy} \\ \text{3rd} & \text{boy} & \text{girl} \\ \text{4th} & \text{boy} & \text{boy}  \end{array} $$
You've ruled out the fourth possibility. Now treat the other three as equally probable.